# Why does UDT use SOCK_STREAM if it is based on UDP?

Tags: sockets, udp

Found the following in the example code `appserver.cpp` distributed with UDT

```
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
```

Why would UDT use SOCK_STREAM and not SOCK_DGRAM?

Comment: I do not know the UDT protocol - but if its says its using UDP and using SOCK_STREAM - then I agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ***can*** be perfectly normal.

If I didn't know anything about UDT, then I would assume that "hints" is likely an instance of addrinfo and used as the second parameter of [getaddrinfo()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)

If the code is just trying to get the IP address of a server (i.e. DNS lookup), then it has to pass something into the hints structure for socktype.  Otherwise, the result of getaddrinfo is likely to return 3x the the number of results.  One result for SOCK_STREAM, another for SOCK_DGRAM, and a third for SOCK_RAW.  But the ai_addr member for each will be the same address.

Now I did just take a peak at the [UDT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/udt/) code. Never heard of it until now.  But it does appear to have some code that is doing some SOCK_STREAM stuff and using getaddrinfo as a formal way to initialize a sockaddr for subsequent TCP connect.

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 

UDTSOCKET fhandle = UDT::socket(hints.ai_family, hints.ai_socktype,hints.ai_protocol); 

if (0 != getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &peer))
{
   cout << "incorrect server/peer address. " << argv[1] << ":" << argv[2] << endl;
   return -1;
}

// connect to the server, implict bind
if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::connect(fhandle, peer->ai_addr, peer->ai_addrlen))
```

But you'll have to ask the UDT developers what it's all about.

Comment: Appreciate your time and effort in looking up UDT. +1. I think your explanation makes sense, till someone else comes up with a more confirmed answer. Thanks again

Comment: What additional information do you need to get a "more confirmed answer" ?

Comment: Not to downplay you in any way but I got an impression you did a visual inspection of the UDT library, and did not actually use it in your code, or so it appears. So we cannot rule out unwanted side-effects. I myself did not get much of a chance to play with UDT either.

Answer (score 2):

UDT is the  UDP-based data transfer protocal,so in all it's is just UDP.
check the UDT Manual
[link](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/index.htm)。it says

> UDT is connection oriented, for both of its SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM mode. connect must be called in order to set up a UDT connection.

so whatever we use,we all have to do a connect() call. so what's the difference?
In SOCK_STREAM,we can use udt's send() API,while in SOCK_DGRAM,we only can use udt's sendmsg() API.

check the manual's "transfer data" and "Messaging with Partial Reliability",i think it may be do a little help.